# Angular Routing : Need to prevent navigation when url typed in browser's address bar is invalid

Tags: angular, url, routes, navigation, window

requirement is to check the browser URL if the user has typed it manually. If URL entered is invalid or if the user is not having access to it, stay on the same page with some warning popup.

I have tried the following -

CanDeactivate - this does not get triggered on hitting enter in the address bar.
CanActivate - the present URL on which I am currently on is getting lost. All I can do is test the target URL. And redirection activity can be performed.
CanLoad - same as CanActivate. current URL is getting lost.

Window.onbeforeunload - Not able to access the target URL from the address bar.

Let me know if this requirement is achievable and How.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict access to a URL, using a warning modal isn't the way to go.

A user, having access to the HTML, can easily bypass that.

Furthermore, Angular provides no built-in way of doing that, so you will have to code your own (maybe through a resolver, but that won't prevent the page from loading).

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(  private router: Router) {
   if ( "some condition") {
      this.router.navigate( ['/Home'] );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through few methods you can prevent access (Inteceptor, Wildcard route, CanActive guard) where system prevents accidental or invalid access

***01)*** If you want to prevent unauthorized access, you can use Interceptor. Form the back-end, you should provide the User Role  (Eg : SYSTEM_ADMIN)

**In unauthorized.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UnauthorizedInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if ([401, 403].indexOf(err.status) !== -1) {               
                // YOUR POP UP MESSAGE
            }

            const error = err || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

**In AppModule.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ...,
    [{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UnauthorizedInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }]
})
```

***02)*** Use angular router wildcard -This helps to redirect the page to `PageNotFoundComponent` if no any url found in your routing. **Remember wildcard route should be the last route.**

```
{path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```

***03)*** Use canActive Guard

In route

```
{
    path: "customer/view",
    component: CustomerViewComponent,
    data: { role: ["SYSTEM_ADMIN"] }
}
```

In AuthGuard.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor (private auth: AuthService, private router: Router, public toster: ToastrManager,) {
}
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        //get the current user value
        const currentUser = this.auth.currentUserValue;      
        if (currentUser) {

            // check if route is restricted by role 
            if (route.data.role && route.data.role.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
                this.toster.errorToastr("Your do not have permission to access", "Not Authorized", { position: "bottom-right", animate: "slideFromBottom" });
                return;
            }

            // authorised so return true
            return true;
    }

     // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
     this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
     return false;
    }
}
```